Find all $\tilde{f}$-invariant measures on $S^1.$
Here is the question I am trying to solve:
let $X = \mathbb R$ and let $f: X \to X$ defined by $f(x) = x + 1.$
1- Use Poincaré recurrence to show that there are no finite $f$-invariant probability measures.
2- Show that $f$ induces a map $\tilde{f}$ from the one point compactification of $\mathbb R$ (i.e., the circle $S^1$) to itself.
3- Find all $\tilde{f}$-invariant measures on $S^1.$
My thoughts:
Regarding 1- when applying my function to the unit interval, I know that I am always coming outside the unit interval by my function so by PR if $\mu$ is f invariant probability preserving dynamical system then I know that $\mu (unit interval) = 0.$ But then what? Is this the full solution?
Regarding 2-, my question is what is $\tilde{f}(\infty)$?
Regarding 3-, I do not know how to tackle it, any hints will be greatly appreciated!

Before starting, let me point out that it may be an impediment to insist on identifying the one point compactification of $\mathbb R$ with $S^1$. Instead, keep in mind that they are homeomorphic; perhaps keep in mind an actual formula for a homeomorphism if you have one at hand; but always remember that they are different objects.
Regarding 1, you have found that the unit interval has measure zero. However, the unit interval is not the entirety of $\mathbb R$. For a hint in proceeding: What about the measure of the interval $[1,2]$? What about measure of the interval $[n,n+1]$ in general? And then what about the measure of the entirety of $\mathbb R$?
Regarding 2, $\tilde f(\infty)=\infty$.
Regarding 3, another hint, assuming that you were actually asked to find all $\tilde f$-invariant probability measures: since $\mathbb R$ is a $\tilde f$-invariant subset of the one point compactification of $\mathbb R$, you can use the first step to deduce the measure of $\mathbb R$.

How can we complete the proof of 2?
